# Why are my PNG files getting stretched with shape Export in PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

According to the intellisense prompt, the Export method in VBA takes the following inputs:

`Export(PathName As String, Filter As PpShapeFormat, [ScaleWidth As Long], [ScaleHeight As Long],[ExportMode As PpExportMode = ppRelativeToSlide])`.

I have not found sufficient documentation from Microsoft to understand the proper usage in regard to the `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight` parameters. They seem to be rather arbitrary. I used 2131 and 1200 (determined by trial and error) respectively to achieve the correct aspect ratio and sufficient image resolution. The resultant PNG file was 1917 pixels wide by 1532 pixels high. Note that the ratio 2131:1200 is quite different from 1917:1532. When the `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight` parameters are not specified, the exported image has the correct aspect ratio, but the resolution is rather low: 864 pixels wide by 690 pixels high. In contrast, bypassing VBA by right clicking on the "Shape" on any particular slide and choosing "Save as Picture..." yields a PNG file that is 1350 pixels wide by 1079 pixels high.

Why aren't the width-to-height ratios of exported images equal to the `ScaleWidth`-to-`ScaleHeight` ratio, and when `ScaleWidth` and `ScaleHeight` aren't provided, why is the PNG file resolution different than when the "Save as Picture..." approach is used manually? How can I make sure to get the resolution I need while maintaining the correct aspect ratio (the width-to-height ratio of the shape in the slide)?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
Sub CombineImages()
    
    ' Initialize variables
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim sld_nmbr As Integer

    sld_nmbr = 0

    ' Loop through all slides in presentation.
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

        sld.Select

        For x = 1 To sld.Shapes.Count
            Set shp = sld.Shapes(x)
            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To x)
            Arr(x) = shp.Name
        Next x
        
        Set sr = sld.Shapes.Range(Arr)

        If UBound(Arr) = 1 Then
            Set shp_f = sld.Shapes(Arr(sld.Shapes.Count))
        Else
            ' Group all shapes on slide.
            Set shp_f = sr.Group
        End If

        ' Export the shape or grouped shapes to PNG file.
        Call ActivePresentation.Slides(sld.Name).Shapes(shp_f.Name).Export("C:\Users\username\temp\" _
        & sld_nmbr & ".png", _
        ppShapeFormatPNG, shp_f.Width, shp_f.Height)

        ' Increment slide number.
        sld_nmbr = sld_nmbr + 1

    Next sld

End Sub
```

***Disclaimers:***

1. Modify the export path to point to an existing directory on your file system.
2. Use a simple PowerPoint presentation to test this code. Make sure that each slide has one or more shape objects only and that they're originally "ungrouped".

Comment: Have you tried running your code sample? First it errors at _ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To x)_ because you haven't declared the array. Once that's fixed, it errors at _Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Export("C:\Users\username\temp\" & sld_Names(sld_nmbr), ppShapeFormatPNG, 2130, 1200)_ with Compile error: Sub or Fiunction not defined, and _sld_Names_ is highlighted..

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKorchok for alerting me to the errors in my code. I am updating my sample code block now. I was a bit too hasty in pasting in the "simplified" version. With that said, other stack overflow users will need to update the username field in the Export path.

Comment: I updated and thoroughly tested the code. Other users will need to update the username field and either modify the path in the Export method or create a 'temp' directory in the user folder.

Comment: Your code still errors at "Call ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Export...", probably because Export is not a method for a ShapeRange. Selecting the slide is not necessary, selecting the shapes on the slide in not needed. Learn to work with ranges instead of selections, they are faster and more reliable. Most placeholders are not groupable and will cause your code to fail.

Comment: @JohnKorchok, thank you for your patience. I was able to run the `...ShapeRange(1).Export...` version of the code on my system. However, per your request, I updated the code (above) to use `Call ActivePresentation.Slides(sld.Name).Shapes(shp_f.Name).Export...`. After changing the code, the PNGs were created successfully; however, their proportions are still incorrect.